# Anyone using Artisteer with Orchard CMS to create Themes?

Tags: orchardcms

Microsoft's new open-source CMS Orchard comes with a small number of Themes (page layout templates).

I would like to have a tool a designer could use (such as Artisteer) to generate new themes.

Has anyone used Artisteer, or another designer friendly tool, to generate themes for Orchard?

Answer (score 3):

There is no such a tool for the moment, **but** you can simplify your life by using code-generator that comes with orchard. You can read about it [here](http://orchardproject.net/docs/Writing-a-new-theme.ashx).

Also following liks might be helpfull:

[Anatomy of the Theme](http://orchardproject.net/docs/Anatomy-of-a-theme.ashx)

[Template File Syntax Guide](http://orchardproject.net/docs/Template-file-syntax-guide.ashx)

[UI Guidelines for Theme Authors](http://orchardproject.net/docs/UI-guidelines-for-theme-authors.ashx)

Answer (score 1):

Artisteer doesn't work with Orchard.

Take a loot at http://orchard.tuning.bind.pt